# Создание случайных переменных и присваивание им элемента из set

Tags: python

Существует сет с числовыми значениями. К примеру: `{'1', '2', '3'}`

Данный сет нужно поместить в функцию, в которую нельзя помещать сеты и словари (как я понял). `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'to_dic'`

Варианты:
1) Создание случайных переменных и присваивание им элементов из set. (как это сделать?)
2) Еще какие-либо?

Comment: какая связь между заголовком вопроса и `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'to_dic'` ошибкой. Вопрос неясен. Какой вывод вы ожидаете? При чем здесь "случайные переменные и присваивание"?

Answer (score 0):

Я правильно понял, что вам нужно получить dict из set?

Тогда это делается так:

1-й способ:

```
s = {1,2,3,4,5}
d = dict.fromkeys(s, 0)
```

Результат:

```
{1: 0, 2: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0}
```

2-й способ:

```
s = {1,2,3,4,5}
d = dict([(elem, 0) for elem in s])
```

3-й способ:

```
s = {1,2,3,4,5}
d = {e:0 for e in s}
```

Comment: `dict([(e, 0) for e in {1,2,3,4,5}])` можно заменить на `dict((e, 0) for e in {1,2,3,4,5})`